# Lie derivative in Kahler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I have the following question

$X$- a compact Kahler manifold and $v\in \Gamma(X,TX)$- Killing vector field. I don't understand why Lie derivatives equal to zero

1. $L_v \omega=0$ where $\omega$ is the Kahler form
2. $L_vI=0$ where $I$ is the complex structure

My attempt is the following. Killing field is satisfied the following equation $L_vg=0$. We have known from the definition that A Kahler Manifold is an hermitian manifold, whose Kälher form is closed. It follows that $d\omega=0$. Let $h$-hermitian metric and from the famous theorem we know that there is a correspondence between $h \to \omega=-Im  h$. And we have that $g(m,n)=\omega(m,In)$, where $I$ is the complex structure. And we can obtain the result or am I a wrong about the first statement?

I don't know what to do with the second statement. If you don't mind please explain it in more details. Thank you!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133700/every-real-holomorphic-hamiltonian-vector-field-on-a-k%C3%A4hler-manifold-is-killing

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Thank you for your answer. It seems that my first part is right.

Comment: Yes, and the second part follows because a real Killing field is holomorphic. <> Kobayashi's _Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry_ may be a useful resource.